# Getting Emgu CV Motion Detection sample working: Unable to load DLL 'opencv_legacy249'

Tags: dll, emgucv

I'm trying to get the [Motion Detection Emgu CV example](https://github.com/artemisvision/emgu_openCV/tree/master/Emgu.CV.Example/MotionDetection) mentioned in [the answer to "Looking for a function for motion detection on emgucv"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18403594/575530) working.

To get the example code working I first needed to

1. add references to the Emgu CV DLLs `Emgu.CV`, `Emgu.CV.UI`, and `Emgu.Util` to the project
2. make sure that the relevant Open CV DLLs (listed on [the EMGU wiki](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation#Have_you_copied_the_OpenCV_dlls_to_the_execution_directory.3F) and found in `C:\Emgu\emgucv-windows-universal-gpu 2.4.9.1847\bin\x86`) are copied always to the output executable directory of the project
3. change the build target to x86

When execution gets to the line in `Form1.cs`

```
_forgroundDetector = new BGStatModel<Bgr>(image, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.BG_STAT_TYPE.FGD_STAT_MODEL);
```

it throws the exception `Unable to load DLL 'opencv_legacy249': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)`. Looking at the execution directory the DLL *is* there:

[image: Explorer screenshot showing required DLL's presence]

What's going on? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

I think I had a version clash. If I take the above steps with the motion detection example as it installs with Emgu CV, i.e. from `C:\Emgu\emgucv-windows-universal-gpu 2.4.9.1847\Emgu.CV.Example\MotionDetection` instead of http://github.com/artemisvision/emgu_openCV/tree/master/Emgu.CV.Example/MotionDetection then it works.