# Does EmguCV BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 could extract background for background subtraction?

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv

I am using AbsDif as a way to determine the object that are present in the image that was not in the background. My problem is that AbsDif is very sensitive in lighting that's why I want to extract the background from the camera feeds. I can't get many backgrounds for different time interval because there are people always present in the camera's view. My objective is that to know the density or volume of how the object in the image.

For example there are plenty of people present in the image, I must be able to get the estimate congestion or crowded-ness in percentage basis like 85% congested something like that.

Comment: I'm reading it but not comprehending. What *exactly* is your question?

Comment: My question is if I could implement and use BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 and BackgroundSubtractorMOG in EmguCV the way it is used in OpecnCV?

Comment: Ok, then have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18986215/2065121) and [this EmguCV motion detection example](https://github.com/artemisvision/emgu_openCV/tree/master/Emgu.CV.Example/MotionDetection)? Do they help?

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/video/background_subtraction/background_subtraction.html#background-subtraction something like this.

Comment: @Roger, that's what I want to try in Emgucv http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/video/background_subtraction/background_subtraction.html#background-subtraction