# Implement and trigger on detected motion

Tags: c#, emgucv

How can I implement a simple motion-detection method using EMGUCV? I have searched for applicable examples, but the only solutions I found were too complicated to implement.

Is there a way I can implement a simple method to detect motion in order to trigger something in my application?

Comment: The problem itself sounds complicated. Maybe you should try to use one of the complicated solutions.

Comment: @user3500876 I think what nvoigt is trying to tell you is: If most solutions are complicated, it probably means there isn't a good, simple solution.

Answer (score 3):

1. Convert a single frame to grayscale.
2. Convert a new frames from real time into grayscale.
3. Make abstractions between the first frame and new frame from real time.

The result of this is a third, new frame comprised of the differences between the first two. Use erosion and thresholding for that to get a frame with white representing the motioned section and black representing the rest of the space.

Here is a piece of code:

```
    using System;

    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using System.ComponentModel;

    using System.Data;

    using System.Drawing;

    using System.Linq;

    using System.Text;

    using System.Windows.Forms;

    using Emgu.CV;

    using Emgu.CV.UI;

    using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;

    using Emgu.CV.Structure;

    using System.Diagnostics;

    using System.IO;

    using System.Data.SqlClient;

    using System.Data.SqlServerCe;

    using System.Drawing.Imaging;

    namespace ptuxiakh___
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {


    Capture _capture = new Capture();

    Capture capture2 = new Capture();

    Image<Bgr, Byte> FirstImage = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(640, 480);
    Image<Bgr, Byte> RealTimeImage = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(640, 480);

    Image<Gray, Byte> des = new Image<Gray, Byte>(640, 480);
    Image<Gray, Byte> thres = new Image<Gray, Byte>(640, 480);
    Image<Gray, Byte> eroded = new Image<Gray, Byte>(640, 480);

    bool baground = false;


     private void Background()
            {

                try{
                FirstImage = _capture.QueryFrame();
                background = true;

                 }
                catch(Exception e)
                  {
                  baground = false;
                  }
            }

     private void Tracking(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

      if (baground == true)
                {
     RealTimeImage   = capture2.QueryFrame();

                    CvInvoke.cvAbsDiff(FirstImage.Convert<Gray, Byte>(), RealTimeImage.Convert<Gray, Byte>(), des);
                    CvInvoke.cvThreshold(des, thres, 20, 255, THRESH.CV_THRESH_BINARY);
                    CvInvoke.cvErode(thres, eroded, IntPtr.Zero, 2);
                  }
                 else
                 {
                 Background(); // At first trying to get a static frame for 
                            // abstraction with real time frame 
                 }
           }


 private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Idle += new EventHandler(Tracking);
        }

 private void Stopbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Idle -= new EventHandler(Tracking);
        }
```

//eroded will be your relust